# Margin left in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can I add a class similar to this **.ml-xl-5** in bootstrap, since I want a margin bigger than 48px?

---

And how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a custom class in your own css stylesheet like this:

```
.ml-xl-6 { // change ml-xl-6 to whatever name or value you want
    margin: 64px; // change 64px to whatever value you want
}
```

And you can use that class anywhere you want the custom margin to be applied on just as you would with a default bootstrap class like this:

```
<div class="ml-xl-6">
    <p>some text content here</p>
</div>
```

---

**N.B.** As @bhmahler mentioned in the comments, an important point that we need to understand and remember is that, in Bootstrap, the `xl` in the class name refers to screen size. If you want to duplicate how bootstrap does it (say, you want `ml-sm-6` or `ml-md-6` to resize accordingly too), you will need to add media queries for the respective screen sizes and add `ml-xl-6`, `ml-l-6`, `ml-sm-6`, `ml-xs-6`, etc in your css stylesheets too.

Comment: Something to note is that the xl in the class name in bootstrap refers to screen size.  If you want to duplicate how bootstrap does it, you will need to add media queries for the screen sizes and add ml-xl, ml-l ml-sm ml-xs etc to their respective media screen sizes

Comment: @bhmahler Good point. Adding it to the question. Thanks man!!